# Word Crimes: A capitalized "A" in some really bold text

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

```
Everybody shut up
Everyone listen up
Hey, hey, hey... hey, hey, hey... hey, hey, hey

If you want to comment in the proper way
You want to split "Show 1 More Comment"
From "Add A Comment"

You need to know Title Case
And what gets capitalised
You wouldn't do "This Is A Vase"
Our site's been vandalised

This isn't on Meta Stack Exchange
Because they don't have the same change
They have "add a comment" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads#comment777320_235255
Their caps are in the basement

"Add A Comment | Show 1 More Comment" is much too bold
Don't do that unless your name is Prince http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106125/bounty-message-is-too-bold
I think this question's getting old
So I'm going to finish
```

Comment: I tried to answer in tone, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: WTF is going on here?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed if you're referring to the tone of the question, it's loosely inspired by Yankovic's song "Word Crimes" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_Crimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved [as of graduation](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/site-design-updates-are-live).

Therefore, it is not a problem any longer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that CSS doesn't have the same capitalization rules

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

is the culprit, the HTML is actually in lower case

```
<a class="js-add-link comments-link " 
   title="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. 
          Avoid answering questions in comments." 
   href="#">add a comment</a>
```

The *larger* problem is that links are badly formatter pretty much everywhere, the single solution which is almost universally used on the web, color, is not adopted. Instead we have a random mix of bold, underline, and ...nothing.

I'm forwarding this to the design team.