# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

Based on the [recent design pitch and your feedback](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/site-design-updates-are-on-the-way), site design updates are now live. Along with the new design, we've made other less apparent changes that allow us to:

- update the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future,
- update most of the graphics to SVG for retina support,
- fix a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network,
- plus we've launched the new user profile!

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know.

Thank you for all of your feedback.

Comment: I... am... speechless... thanks! Finally we have some dignity :-)

Comment: I saw it, and just wanted to click Like on everything!

Comment: Wow... This looks like a real site now. I may have to start taking the answers here seriously.

Comment: @Shog9, have you learned NOTHING here?!?! Never embrace possibly false messages just because the medium is so lovely!!  You have *completely* failed this skepticism test.  See, Kurtis?  I told you they weren't ready for such beauty.  :P

Comment: Pfft; next you'll be telling me that the charts in USA Today aren't a reliable source.

Answer (score 16):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Suggested by [Oddthinking:](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/menu-items-should-have-larger-clickable-areas)

In the fancy new design, the menu in the top right of the page (Questions/Tags/Users/etc) has boxes that highlight when you are on that page. It is suggestive that the whole box is a clickable target.

However, in fact only the words are clickable, so this is a false affordance.

Please make the entire area hoverable/clickable.

i.e. I should be able to change to the Tags page by clicking where the red cross is.

> [image: Example]

Comment: +1 - I had the same experience, but convinced myself I just had strange expectations there.

Comment: We'll fix this soon.

Comment: I just ran across the new site design and A) was impressed and thought hey cool, let me explore, then B) ran into that click taraget issue within seconds. All the visual design clues suggest a bigger tarket that the actual copy.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers *bump* How soon is soon?

Comment: @Tim It's updated now. Had to adjust the way it was built a bit to get things to work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

The "times N" indicators for the badges are vertically misaligned. Yay CSS!

[image]

Comment: This was already mentioned in Meta Stack Exchange...

Comment: @PythonMaster better to mention on the site surely?

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Wow, I am really impressed. The new design is simple, yet elegant.

Just one thing, shouldn't favicons' background be transparent instead of white?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Good catch. We're fixing this soon.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The `S` is barely visible when using dark themes. Can't please everyone. :D

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can you update the style for our chat pages?

- http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=people&host=skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sure. The chat update is on the way.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

"Featured on Meta" box icon display error:

[image]

Comment: Also happens for "Hot Network Questions".

Comment: This should be fixed now.