# Menu items should have larger clickable areas

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the fancy new design, the menu in the top right of the page (Questions/Tags/Users/etc) has boxes that highlight when you are on that page. It is suggestive that the whole box is a clickable target.

However, in fact only the words are clickable, so this is a false affordance.

Please make the entire area hoverable/clickable.

i.e. I should be able to change to the Tags page by clicking where the red cross is.

> [image: Example]

Comment: It is better to post this as an answer  here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/site-design-updates-are-live

Comment: I don't see the advantages of that. Here, the issue can be dealt with separately.

Comment: No, we're posting answers there to request design changes since it is new.  The designer already processed most of our requests. I have posted it there yesterday and it is being dealy with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been updated. We had to adjust the way things were built a bit. Thanks.