# Remove numbers above navlink titles in upper right corner?

Tags: bug, design

The small numbers above the words in the upper right (shown in the screenshot in George Chalhoub's [answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3403/27319) on the "Site design updates are live!" post) are confusing: they seem like they're indicating keyboard shortcuts and that pressing those numbers will somehow lead to those pages.  If the numbers are just decorative, they should probably be removed or at least changed to avoid giving the impression that they are functional.

Comment: I completely agree. They threw me off at first, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I can still see this on both meta and main:

[image]
[image]

On macOS, with Chrome, Firefox 57, Safari.

Comment: I'm seeing it with Firefox on Windows, too.  Any thoughts, @Sklivvz?

Comment: @WBT meh, I had misread the question